# apostrophe not escaped on second entry

Tags: mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, apostrophe

i have a simple form with a textarea and a save button.
what is entered in the field is stored in mysql and then displayed on another page.
each time you enter stuff in the textarea and save, it saves it on top of what is already stored, making an even longer string, if you see what i mean.

im using mysql_real_escape_string

on testing, when i enter an apostrophe for the first time it is displayed as \' which is correct. but when i enter an apostrophe again it breaks down

what is going on?

thanks

Comment: ahh. sorry. just worked it out. i wasnt escaping the original data that was being stored and then added on to the new data - if that makes sense

Comment: Then answer your own question properly - with an answer. Oh, and this should have been tagged *php* as well.

Comment: I've been sitting here for five hours, waiting for the idiot who locked his bike to mine to show up, so that I can go home. In the circumstances, I think I'm being amazingly calm and helpful.

Comment: ha, yea fair enough. ive had that happen to me. someone put their lock through my brake cable, had to spend sometime undoing it all. hope you didnt have to wait too much longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh. sorry. just worked it out. i wasnt escaping the original data that was being stored and then added on to the new data - if that makes sense